# Launch a Jenkins job at a specific time

Tags: jenkins

I have the need to launch a Jenkins job at a user defined time.

To clarify, I have an intranet site that in a web interface allows the user to choose a Jenkins job from a select and with a button that when is clicked invokes the Jenkins webservices and launches the choosen job. This part is already workinng correctly.

Now I have to add to the web interface a field in which the user can enter a date time value, to specifiy an exact time at which the job must be run.

Can I pass this information to Jenkins along with the job name and then in Jenkins schedule the job to be executed at the specified time? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to use Jenkins feature - 
Build Triggers - Build periodically?

Comment: I knew the answer, but then found a duplicate. Not very fun. There is a hint here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build , under *Launching a build with parameters*.

Comment: I did not found the linked question before opening this one, and it answers my problem, so I'm voting for closing this one. Thanks to all.